# Migrator.NET MSBuild - Could not load file or assembly 'Migrator.Framework'

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, migration

I've installed Migrator.NET using NuGet but when I attempt to run a migration using MSBuild I get the following error. I see that its having trouble accessing the Migrator.Framework assembly but I am unsure as to why or where specifically I need to put the DLL in order to get it to run.

C:\Users\Cody\src\App\App.Migrations\App.Migrations.csproj(64,5): error MSB4062: The "Migrator.MSBuild.Migrate" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\Cody\src\App\App.Migrations..\packages\MigratorDotNet.0.9.0.33276\tools\Migrator.MSBuild.dll.

Could not load file or assembly 'Migrator.Framework, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3b3586e9632ecfce' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Does anyone have any insight? I've spent far too long fiddling with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the issue was in fact that it was looking for version 0.0.0.0. I downloaded the project and recompiled the Migrator.Framework binary as version 0.0.0.0 as a quick fix. The real solution is recompiling Migrator.MSBuild.dll to look for the proper version of Migrator.Framework.

I'll see if this was a one-off error or if I can reproduce it, and submit it as a bug to the Migrator.NET team if it is in fact a bug with the NuGet package.

Comment: This is a solution indeed, but you can also use the previous version that is working ok, while the new version is not fixed. You can do this by forcing Nuget to install a specific version of MigratorDotNet: Install-Package MigratorDotNet -Version 0.9.0.28138

Comment: Thanks sir... I've used migrator.net before w/out nuget and just copied the binaries from different project to project... Wondered why all of the sudden I got this error on the nuget pull